# What is the most effective way of writing a factory method?

Tags: java, design-patterns, factory, factory-pattern, effective-java

In most of the cases when we write a factory method it is a bunch of `if` conditions which can keep on growing. What is the most effective way of writing such a method (with the least `if` conditions)?

```
public A createA(final String id) {
    if (id.equals("A1")) {
      return new A1();
    }
    else if (id.equals("A2")) {
      return new A2();
    }
    return null;
  }
```

Comment: On stackoverflow, this question is likely to be closed as being subjective. For this kind of programming style question, http://programmers.stackechange.com would have been a better fit.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could use a `Map<String, Supplier<A>>`:

```
Map<String, Supplier<A>> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("A1", () -> new A1());
map.put("A2", () -> new A2());

...

public A createA(final String id) {
    Supplier<A> supplier = map.get(id);
    if (supplier != null) {
        return supplier.get();
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("unknown id: " + id);
}
```

This uses a standard Java 8 [Supplier](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Supplier.html) interface, with a Java 8 lambda syntax, but you could of course define your own Supplier interface, and create instances using anonymous inner classes.

Comment: Not too familiar with lambdas, but is this lazy or eager initialization?

Comment: It's lazy. The get() call calls the body of the lambda. Passing () -> new A1(); where a Supplier<A> should go is roughly equivalent to (deep breath) new Supplier<A>() { public A get() { return new A1(); } }. Supplier<A> is a [functional interface](http://java.dzone.com/articles/introduction-functional-1).

Comment: @Calum This is technically eager. An anonymous class is constructed immediately, which creates new instances of some class via the _get()_ method, but at no point is the creation of an object delayed until it is needed.

Comment: I meant to express that it's delaying the construction of A1 instances until they're needed but I take your meaning. It doesn't solve the problem of returning a single A1 instance to all callers if that's what's being asked.

Answer (score 1):

I like a archetype map approach - just fill the archetypes up at some stage - either in a static block or the class constructor. Code looks roughly like this

```
  Map<String, A> archetypes;

  public A createA(final String id)
  {
     A a = archetypes.get(id);
     return (a!=null)?a.copy():null;
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

This method is lazy initialization. Assuming you have classes that correspond to the name in `id`:

```
public A createA(final String id) {
  // warning, should not use an id string that is tainted (eg from user input)
  return (A) Class.forName(id).newInstance();
}
```

Comment: Creating classes by name should be avoided if possible. It leads to lots of problems if you have non flat classloaders like in OSGi or JavaEE.